# Django: Why is timezone.now() off by one day?

Tags: python, django, datetime

When I call django's `timezone.now()`, I get this result

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 29, 1, 14, 22, 49332, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Which is completely off (it's actually 9 o' clock on July 28).

Why is django's timezone off? Is there a way to fix it? I know the problem doesn't lie in python's datetime because calling `datetime.datetime.now()` results in

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 28, 21, 17, 8, 957951)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using UTC time (notice this `tzinfo=<UTC>`).  In this case, it is +4 hours from your time.